# How to lookup if a date-time cell is "AM" or PM" and return a value in a different column?

Tags: excel, algorithm, excel-formula, trend

I have a data dump with many different fields/columns of information. The particular column of interest contains a date-time format i.e "1/2/2019  6:30:00 AM". I need to check whether the time is 6:30 AM or 6:30 PM and then return a value next to the date-time column containing the name of the operator starting at that time.

I have already tried to format the cells to contain only the time and work from there but still not luck. I also tried to use wildcards like "*" but couldn't get them to work in the formula to lookup cells "containing AM/PM".

I can use lookup function to lookup a date and return the operators name corresponding to that date but I need a way to separate the operators by AM and PM. Assuming everyday theres a new operator at 6:30 AM and at 6:30 PM.
This is a very specific type of question and I can clarify anything that is unclear.

Comment: But these are textvalues, formatted to look like a date/time? So all cells will have 11 characters from the right describing the time? Or are these actual date/time values? A lot of these datadumps seem to just have textvalues.

Comment: To really give this an attempt we'd also need to see the format of the schedule data you have for each employee because your question isn't really "how do I get AM or PM from a given time" it's more like "how do I determine whether two times overlap"

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want if the dates are serial numbers: https://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/toms-tutorials-for-excel-verifying-a-time-as-am-or-pm/

If dates are text values, then `=RIGHT(A1,2)` will do the trick.

Comment: While this answers the question in the title, it doesn't actually solve the problem OP has (although the question is a bit out of scope because there's no current attempt)

Comment: True but either solutions can be used in a more complex formula or inserted where needed by the OP.